# How to show high resolution image into thumbnails ? in iPhone /iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am downloading image of size 3.4 Mb and need to show in a preview icon and then full image size . But Application crash . what is the method to show very high resolution image into thumbnail by objective c /iPhone sdk .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, loading lots of images with this size, you load a lot of memory.

There are some good extensions that help you resizing images. Have a look here, I use it, it's simple and I recommend it strongly: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/
Have a look at the end of the post if you want only the class extensions.

But if the app is crashing with only one image of 3.4 Mb, it shouldn't crash and maybe it's happening due to another reason.

Comment: I assume the 3.4MB is its *compressed* size. When it comes to memory and images unless it's a raw file the file size isn't helpful.

Comment: But the app is still crashing when you load the image?